# How to randomly generate numbers?

Tags: javascript, for-loop, random

I'm new to javascript and am trying to write a script that will randomly select a number between 1 and 100 and then print each number up to but not including the random integer, except for special cases like 50 in which it prints fifty. So for instance, if it the random integer is 10, it would print 1-9. I've got the first part down but the issue I'm having is how to set the limit on how many numbers will print and how I stop it from writing the random integer as well. Currently, this code will randomly print an infinite amount of numbers and I want it to be no higher than 100. Any ideas? Thanks!

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>Random Number</title>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <script>
        var newNumber ="";
        for( var i=1; (Math.floor(Math.random()*100)); i++) {


            if (i==50) {
                newNumber += "fifty ";

            }
            else {
                NewNumber += i + " ";
            }

        }
        document.write(newNumber);

    </script>
</head>
<body>          
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Note that `newNumber != NewNumber`

Comment: Whoops, yeah I realize that wouldn't work as is. I copied it over and had to change some things and must have missed that, Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the for loop, you need to specify the condition properly, like this

```
for(var i = 1, randMax = (Math.floor(Math.random()*100)); i < randMax; i++) {
```

Here, we generate the random number only once, at the beginning of the for loop and we make sure that, we don't execute the loop more than the random maximum number.

Comment: Thank you! I have a quick question though. How do I make sure the counter starts at 1 because currently it's possible to not print anything and I want to make it so that it at least prints 1.

Comment: @user2395715 As it is, the `counter` starts at `1` only, right?

Comment: Sometimes nothing will appear on the page. Is there a way to ensure that the counter always starts at 1?

Comment: @user2395715 Are you looking for something like [`do...while`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/do...while)?